# Should a free roaming camera movement be controlled by the physics engine (for smooth movement)?

Tags: physics, physics-engine

I have a hobby engine (for fun and research) with a free roaming camera implementation that works by modifying the `PositionComponent` and `CameraDirectionComponent` each frame update (both equivalent to `float3`). Obviously this isn't great as movement speed is tied to framerate. I've read several great posts about [timesteps](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/), but I'm not clear on whether objects that don't have physical interactions (i.e. a free-roam camera) should also be tied into the physics engine? Should *everything* that moves be integrated with the physics engine?

One of the pros I can see is that we can control camera movement by physical velocity. Are there any other approaches to consider?

---

My current rudimentary camera position update is called every frame as part of input handling. The following code is the extracted forward movement implementation:

```
const float multiplier = 1.0f / m_keyboardSensitivity;
const float moveDelta = 0.5f * multiplier;

// m_direction (float3) is the _normalised_ direction the camera is currently pointing
position += m_direction.Scale(moveDelta);
```

Comment: You can achieve smooth notion by correcting the displacement for the elapsed time step without handing full control over the object to a physics engine, so this sounds like a false dichotomy to me. If you'd like help making your camera movement code smoother / better behaved under varying framerate, include it in your question so we can suggest improvements.

Comment: @DMGregory, thanks for the suggestion. I've added code from forward camera movement, though as I mentioned, it's pretty basic right now.

Comment: Not tying camera movement speed to framerate is unrelated to it being controlled by the physics engine. Or, rather, it's not the only way to do it. If you have fixed timestep, you have an update function that runs N times per second, that among other things updates physics. Whether you control the camera from that function directly or through the physics engine doesn't matter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat do you have an example of updating N-times per second? Previous examples I've seen use `deltaTime`, e.g. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-6-keyboard-and-mouse/

Comment: The article you linked (the [fix your timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) one) has it, in the final snippets. `dt` is const there.